# dbbackup specify which pg_dump to use

Tags: python, postgresql, centos, pg-dump, django-1.11

When calling

```py
from django.core.management import call_command
call_command('dbbackup', compress=True, interactive=False)
```

I get:

```py
CommandConnectorError: Error running:  pg_dump xxx --host=localhost --port=xxx --username=xxx --no-password --clean 
pg_dump: server version: 9.6.5; pg_dump version: 8.4.20
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

I'm using a non-root installation of PostgreSQL (version `9.6.5`) as backend for a django application. (Used [this](http://blog.endpoint.com/2013/06/installing-postgresql-without-root.html) tutorial for the installation.)

There is also a postgreSQL installation in the machine (version `8.4.20`).

Before I switched to the non-root installation, everything worked flawlessly.
My guess is that the `pg_dump` called in `dbbackup` is still the one from the root installation.

How can one specify which pg_dump to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have made a non-root installation of postgreSQL, say with the user `nonrootuser`, then you should find `psql` as well as `pg_dump` for this installation under `/home/nonrootuser/postgres/bin/`. This is the `pg_dump` you want to use.

Dbbackup allows you to specify the connector it uses to create the backup. 
In particular it allows you to specify the dump command ([`DUMP_CMD`](https://django-dbbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/databases.html#dump-cmd)).
To specify the connector, add the following block to your settings.py:

```py
import os  # if not yet imported
DBBACKUP_CONNECTORS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'xxx',
        'USER': 'xxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxx',
        'HOST': 'xxx',
        'PORT': 'xxx',
        'DUMP_CMD': os.path.join(
            os.environ["HOME"],
            'nonrootuser',
            'bin',
            'pg_dump'
            )
        }
    }
```

Replace the `xxx` with your specific values.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for that quick answer, I'm trying it out now!

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! I somehow could not find this in the docs of dbbackup :(